# .htaccess redirect users to new servers ip address

Tags: .htaccess, ip

I'm  needing to transfer a website from one cpanel server to another and am trying to minimize downtime while the DNS updates.

I was once told years ago that it was possible to redirect users to a new IP address but after googeling frantically for a few hours I can't seem to find an example of hoe to do this.

Comment: If it's the same domain name, I think you can't do that. Because the client (your browser) has your domain name and it fetches the IP associated to that domain from DNS name servers. Therefore you have to wait for the name servers to update the IP, because such association is not dependent on the files or settings of your old server. Your old server can forward users to the new IP, but not to the same domain with new IP, because, as said, such association depends on third parties which you do not control.

Answer (score 1):

Said old ip is 1.1.1.1

Said development site ip is 2.2.2.2

Said your domain is domain.com and have a DNS A record to 1.1.1.1

- Add a record in your DNS as www2 A 2.2.2.2
- After the DNS time you can go to your www2.domain.com to develop
- When your www2.domain.com is at your taste
- In the domain.com you redirect to www2.domain.com
- You change the DNS A of domain.com to 2.2.2.2
- After the DNS propagation redirect www2.domain.com to domain.com.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that with the following example.

`# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain
Redirect 301 / http://place-your-ip-here/`

More examples can be found [here](http://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file).

Comment: Would this not redirect them based on their own cached DNS? The URL is not changing only the IP address.

Comment: You are right. Before you posted question I edited my answer to suit your question better and changed URL with IP address.